# Virtualizing On a Domain Controller Server

Tags: virtualization, domain, domain-controller

Im Installing a new physical Domain Controller Server 2012, But I want to know if its recommended to virtulize other servers on this Domain Controller Server.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should go the other way around. Dedicate the physical server to only being a virtualization host and run your domain controller as a VM.

Comment: I Think that would be the best, I wanned to virtualize RDP servrices on that Server, But Ill virtulize both Domain Controller and RDP. Thank you for your help.